# Angular Google Maps (AGM) not visible

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-material

I'm trying to add a map to my Angular project. Using AGM to achieve that (https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps).
My map is not showing up though...

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule(<NgModule>{
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    OrderModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: <APIKEY>
    })
  ],

  exports: [FilterPipe],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

app.component.html:

```
<div>
  <agm-map [latitude]="51.678418" [longitude]="7.809007" [zoom]="zoom" [disableDefaultUI]="false"
           [zoomControl]="false">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="51.678418" [longitude]="7.809007"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
</div>
```

I'm showing this in a mat-tab component (angular material)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27):

You're supposed to give the map a height so in your component styles add this:

```
agm-map{
    height: 300px
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

**In HTML template **

```html
<agm-map #map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="styles" [mapTypeId]='mapType' #AgmMap></agm-map>
```

**in TS**

```
  import { AgmMap } from '@agm/core';   

  @ViewChild('map') public agmMap: AgmMap;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.agmMap) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.agmMap.triggerResize();
      }, 100);
    } else {
      console.log('map was not rendered');
    }
  }
```

**In CSS**

```css
agm-map {
  height: 300px !important;
  width: 100%;  /* This is really important*/
}
```

Comment: Just to point out here that, a proper way to triggerResize would be to call it in this.pickMap.triggerResize(); lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using agm(angular google maps) you should provide proper latitude and longitude in attributes. Use proper binding syntax of attributes and provide height in styles.

Answer (score 0):

The most practical way is something like this:

```
<div class="map">
    <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [disableDefaultUI]="false" [scrollwheel]="null" [zoomControl]="true" [styles]="styles">/agm-map>
</div>

.map {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50vh;
    height: 0;

    agm-map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a shared module and if the module where you declared your component (where you want to integrate agm) using this shared module, you will just need to add AgmCoreModule in this shared module

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a map some height so put below code in style.css
agm-map{
height: 300px
}