# When agm-map is inside component, map is not rendered

Tags: angular, google-maps

**Goal**

I'm trying to wrap an `<agm-map>` inside my own `<app-map>` component but is not even being render in the HTML.

[image]

The agm (angular google maps) library is well configured and the maps shows well when the tag  is used alone, but I need to provide my own component

**Things that I have tried**

- https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/issues/1101
- https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/issues/1319
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55099459/1461862

Here are is the code for the component template

**map.component.html**

```html
<agm-map flex #map [latitude]="latitude" [zoomControl]="true" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoomLevel" [zoomControl]="hasZoomControls">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [markerDraggable]="isMarkerDraggable" (dragEnd)="onDragEnd($event)"> </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

**map.component.css**

```css
agm-map {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**map.component.ts**

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AgmMap } from '@agm/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss'],
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() latitude = 0;
  @Input() longitude = 0;
  @Input() zoomLevel = 4;
  @Input() hasZoomControls = true;
  @Input() isMarkerDraggable = true;

  @ViewChild('map') public agmMap: AgmMap;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
    if (this.agmMap) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Resizing');
        this.agmMap.triggerResize();
      }, 100);
    } else {
      console.log('map was not rendered');
    }
  }
  onDragEnd(event): void {
    console.log('dragged');
  }
}
```

And the the `shared.module.ts` I have added the new component

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...,MapComponent]
```

What can I be missing ?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was to export the component on the shared module

```js
exports: [ ..., MapComponent],
```